# How to get filtered image after apply Filters object.applyFilters() ? Any call back their?

Tags: fabricjs

fabric 1* version we was used

```
    Object.applyFilters(function(){ 
            ///// Callback ...... 
    });
```

but now we are in fabric 2* version

```
    Object.applyFilters();
```

So,After ApplyFilters and call back here ? and how we get filtered image.

Comment: `applyFilters` is synchronous. if you are using `object.applyFilters();` filter will apply to object itself.